# Variable Number of Objects in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I want to create something like the "Galery" section in the picture below.
[image]

How would you go about putting in a variable number of objects into a prototype cell? Is it possible to put a scroll view into the cell?

And how would you do the auto layout for the prototype cell, when you don't know how many objects are in it?

Answer (score 0):

Just embed a horizontal `UICollectionView` inside of the tableView cell, where each collection view cell will present one user avatar.